# Codeigniter - move_uploaded_file permission(?) issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

This problem was asked before, but did not solve my case. I am working with Codeigniter.

I have a simple form that submits a file and want to move this file into a folder on my server. After submitting I can print_r the $_FILES['new-item-file'] array and everythings looks good.

But when I use move_uploaded_file I get an error:

failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

The folder I want to write in exists and has 777 permissions.

Dies anyone have a solution to this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: moving uploaded files where ? can you show your code?

Comment: I just want to move it into a folder in the codeignitter root.

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['new-item-file']['tmp_name'], base_url()."sources /".$item_source."_".$_FILES['new-item-file']['name']); base_url() contains a tailing slash.

Comment: move_uploaded_file works with directories so you need to provide a directory not a URL

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

Move_uploaded_file does not seem to accept absolute paths. I took out the base_url(); and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens due to two reasons.

1. Permission of the folder and invalid group and user owner.
2. Wrong path.

### Permission and owner of folder :

If you are in Linux. Open terminal type this command. This will change the owner of the folder.

```
$ cd project_path && sudo chown -R www-data:www-data picture_folder/
```

Type this command to change the permission of folder.

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 picture_folder/
```

note : Use man command more help about these commands.

```
$ man chmod  OR man chown
```

### Path of folder .

In codeigniter, index.php root file is executed. That is responsible for all activities. So don't use base_url() for root path. Instead. Just give root folder name. like

CI application
  ->

-application

-system

-user_guide

-index.php

-picture_folder

```
  $target_directory="picture_folder/sub_folder";
```